# Ruby Nokogiri Ordered HTML tags

Tags: html, ruby, parsing, nokogiri

Background:
I am working on a simple web scraper for learning purposes.  I am trying to scrape the main-headings`<h2>` and the sub-headings `<h3>` elements from the Wikipedia page about the Ruby programming language.  I can access each of these individually, but I would like to write my code in a way that any Wikipedia article could be substituted in.

Main question:
I am looking for a way to list all the `<h3>` elements that lie between the `<h2>` elements on the page.  Is there a way to do that directly via Nokogiri, or will it involve using some Ruby as a work around?

Basically, I want to be able to list the main heading and the accompanying sub-headings, but I can not see a way to group them as Wikipedia does not have them grouped in their html.

Thank you for your time.

-M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use Nokogiri's CSS selectors. The Bastard's Book of Ruby has a good primer on that. http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/html-parsing/

In your case, you'd want to use the following:

```
page.css('h2:not([id]) > span.mw-headline, h3:not([id]) > span.mw-headline')
```

Based on what I see in the dev tools console for Wikipedia pages, the main headings and subheadings do not have ID attributes, which is why I use the `:not([id])` pseudo-selector. It'll look for all h2 and h3 elements that do not have IDs. Each nested span with the heading title has the `.mw-headline` class.

If you only want the h3 elements (each section's sub-heading), you can just have:

```
page.css('h3:not([id]) > span.mw-headline')
```